# SEO, Paging in DataList, How to add all the URLs

Tags: asp.net, seo, url-rewriting

I am using a DataList along with paging with the help of a PagedDataSource. The user moves through pages with the help of next and previous button.

Now, because of that, I am able to create sitemap for the first list of data in all pages and because of it, I am not able to create XML sitemap for it.

How to sort this matter out.

Please note that I am also using URL rewriting using Intelligencia URL Reqriter to change the url from www.mywebsite.com/subject.aspx?subject=NICE-SUBJECT to www.mywebsite.com/subjects/NICE-SUBJECT.aspx.

In this page, there is paging to show the various data, say tutorials, so I am able to create sitemap for the first page only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I followed [this](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/661d37e0-9d95-4f04-897d-77470b6794a8/seo-friendly-paging-with.aspx) tutorial. It had some problems (When you click page 1, page 2 is displayed and if you click pg 2, page 3 is displayed).But it gave me nice starting point.

What I did was to use a page query string and use it set the page index of the PagedDataSource.

Answer (score 0):

If your paging links are HTML, and ultimately expose every page of results, search engines will follow them all.

Comment: he meant if they were individual pages not just HTML or ASPX

Comment: I was talking about the actual links. If they are generated as html, search engines will follow them. If they are are generated as javascript, they can't follow them.